# restarting jquery's setInterval without re-initializing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval, restart

As my title suggests I want to restart jquery's setInterval without re-initializing it.

My scenario is that consider a page that is completely loaded. On this page a `div` gets added dynamically and randomly anytime after the page is completely loaded. I am not adding this `div` from my code behind so I do not have any control over this. This `div` has a class namely `lpInviteChatHrefClose`. This is fixed i.e. the `div` will always have this class. When the user clicks on this div, some javascript function executes and this `div` gets hidden. Also multiple `div` tags might get added (with the same class name) but if an existing, visible `div` tag is not clicked then a new `div` is not added.

Now, what I want to achieve is that I want to call a javascript function on click of this `div`. Now, since this `div` is dynamically added, I cannot write the following as jquery will not be able to find the `div` on `document.ready`

```
$('.lpInviteChatHrefClose').click(function(){...});
```

So what I did is I created a `setInterval` which checks if such `div` exists, if yes then bind the click event. I was able make this work when the first time the dynamic `div` gets added.

My problem arises when the second time this dynamic `div` gets added to the html. Here again i need to handle the click event of the new dynamically added `div`.

What I have done so far is as follows

**outside document.ready (global)**

```
 var interval;

 var onInterval;
```

**inside document.ready**

```
onInterval = function () {
    //check if an element with this class exists
    if ($('.lpInviteChatHrefClose').length) {
        $(".lpInviteChatHrefClose").click(function () {
            outbound_reject_omniture_setting(this);
            //This should restart the interval but it doesnt
            interval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
        });
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
};

interval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
```

I would have done away with this check `if ($('.lpInviteChatHrefClose').length)` but then the `setInterval` will attach a function after every 1 second as soon as the dynamic `div` appears. I do not want this. I want that my javascript function should get called only once.

**The `clearInterval(interval);` will stop/pause the interval. But I have no idea how to restart it.**

Please help!

Sorry for the long description. Thanks in advance!

Comment: setInterval is not jQuery.. is pure Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this.

The problem was that the `setInterval` was getting restarted (an observation mistake you can say) but it was getting bound immediately to an earlier element which was created dynamically hence new element which was getting added after certain period of time was not getting bound.

Also as I mentioned that the method which was getting called i.e. `outbound_reject_omniture_setting` was doing some work and then the element was getting hidden, so I was not able to check if the click is getting bound to the same element.

The solution was to loop through all the elements that are added till now dynamically and check if any 1 of them is `visible`. If yes then bound the click event to the element and clear the interval. Within the click function, restart the interval.

```
onInterval = function () {
    $('.lpInviteChatHrefClose').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).css('visibility') == 'visible') {
            $(this).click(function () {
                outbound_reject_omniture_setting(this);
                interval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
            });
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    })
};

interval = setInterval(onInterval, 1000);
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegated event handler to attach events to elements which are created after DOMready has fired. Forget anything to do with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.lpInviteChatHrefClose', function(){
    // your code here...
});
```

Comment: I have tried this out but this is not working in my scenario. I dont know why. It is not calling even for the first time. After this only i had to use setinterval. Do I need to write this inside document.ready or outside it?

Comment: No i did not. How to check? Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use `setInterval` for dynamic elements. Use event delegation for that

```
$(document).on('click','.lpInviteChatHrefClose',function(){...});
```

Comment: I have tried this out but this is not working in my scenario. I dont know why. It is not calling even for the first time. After this only i had to use setinterval. Do I need to write this inside document.ready or outside it?

Comment: you dont have to put this code in document.ready .This code will definitely work for every element regardless of the condition whether they are created dynamically or not.